# libraries definitions Spark SQL in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a problem with the libraries definition of Hive when I try to use spark.sql (v2.4.4), I was wondering if I need to install Hive?

[image]

Comment: Install JDK 8 and set the environment variables accordingly. Please see the post below https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39183011/why-does-pyspark-fail-with-unable-to-locate-hive-jars-to-connect-to-metastore

Comment: I Installed JDK 8 and set the environment variables accordingly but It didn't work I have the same problem

Comment: What's the environment? Looks like Jupyter or similar? What's the version of the notebook env?